# GKE with Workload identity can't access secrets from Secret Manager through nodejs client library

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-secret-manager, workload-identity, google-cloud-node

Using the below guides:

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/workload-identity-secrets

https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/samples/secretmanager-access-secret-version#secretmanager_access_secret_version-nodejs

One google service account and one kubernetes service account with privileges for both activities.

The identity is working from the pod.

The secrets are accessible from the pod.

When trying to access the secrets through the client library it doesn't return any response - neither secrets nor errors. There is no error object in the API so can't be debugged at the application level.

`async function accessSecretVersion() { const [version] = await client.accessSecretVersion({ name: name, });`

Probably the same issue:
https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-secret-manager/issues/106

It's closed without any solution provided.